# Dynamic id inside AngularJS template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm wrapping a jQuery plugin inside a AngularJS directive. The way I would like to call the directive is for example:

```
<my-dialog data-trigger-id="myTriggerId">My dialog content...</my-dialog>
```

Inside my directive template it looks like this:

```
<button id="{{triggerId}}">Button text...</button>
```

I attach the event for the jQuery plugin (where you specify the trigger selector) inside the link function of my directive. My problem is that it works if I hardcode the id of the button inside the directive template like this:

```
<button id="myTriggerId">Button text...</button>
```

The generated html looks fine in the browser, which means that rendering an element with a dynamic id works. It's just that the jQuery plugin cannot find this element if I use the dynamic id but it works with the hardcoded version.
I also looked up AngularJS compile because it looks like at the point where the jQuery plugin wants to initialize the element doesn't exist yet.

Is there a gotcha I'm missing? Thanks!

Edit: I finally managed to simplify it down and create a jsfiddle example. If you run the example, you will see in the console that the element doesn't exist at the time I'm logging it but if you inspect the DOM, you will see that it's there and has the correct id.
However if you hardcode the id in the template (id=test instead of id={{elemId}}), the console log will show that one element could be found. I hope this helps to find a solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/a1nxyv8u/7/

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or provide the code for your directive so we see what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Its sadly not open source but I will try to create a similar example.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use a unique id instead of using $(element).length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The digest has not yet rendered in the DOM by the time you are calling you $("#test").length.

You need to add in a $timeout so that the digest will complete, then call your method

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('myDialog', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<button id="{{elemId}}" class="{{elemClass}}">Open dialog</button>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var selector = scope.elemSelector,
            elemClass = (selector.indexOf('.') > -1) ? selector.substr(1) : '',
            elemId = (selector.indexOf('#') > -1) ? selector.substr(1) : '';

            scope.elemClass = elemClass;
            scope.elemId = elemId;

            $timeout(function() {
                console.log('elem: ', $('#test').length);
            });
            // jQuery plugin init here but element doesn't seem to exist yet.

        },
        scope: {
            elemSelector: '@'
        }
    }
}]);
```

Although it should be noted that you should try and alleviate any Id's at all and just use $(element) instead unless your jQuery absolutely needs the Id.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and solution. I was beyond making my code work but try to understand what's going on under the hood of AngularJS.
The reason I need the id instead of the element is that the plugin is an overlay which requires a trigger element. I put this trigger element in the directive template. To be able to use multiple of these directives inside a page, I would provide unique ids.

However, I also realized while discussing this issue with a coworker that it's not really the Angular way to wrap jQuery plugins inside directives. I guess that Angular directives need to be KISS.

Comment: Wrapping jQuery plugin inside angular directives is absolutely acceptable... unless there is an angular equivalent of the plugin, which they seem to be sparse.  However, I might suggest creating a unique ID inside your directive instead of having the user pass one in.  You could do something like id='myDirective_$id' and then in your jQuery calls, you could simply do $("#myDirecitve_" + $scope.$id).

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea, which would make it even easier for another developer on the project to use the directive. Obviously I can and will try this out but would this work without the $timeout method?

Comment: I tested with using id="myDirective_{{$id}}" inside the template which works nicely but the $timeout is still required. :)

Comment: Yes, $timeout would still be required.  Glad it worked!